# How to find a more accurate ellipse based on the current detected ellipse

Tags: opencv, ellipse, drawellipse

[image]

I fitted an ellipse based on edges of extracted red ball. But it's not accurate.

I extracted this red ball based on HSV Color Space, but it always ignores the contour of this ball. (Perhaps because color of contour is much darker).

Any good ideas to let me fit a better ellipse for this ball? I want to find an ellipse which can embrace the red ball as accurate as possible.

It will be better if I can use existing functions of OpenCV.

Comment: My first thought would be active contours (aka snakes), however I don't know what the OpenCV implementation is like now - it used to be buggy. Google will help, but [there's an online demo here](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/msn/book/new_demo/Snakes/).

Comment: Can you provide the original image, and the code you tried so far?

Comment: I have posted my source code of this answer, welcome any valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem. It is still unstable, but at most of time it works.

source image. All of those images can be detected: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/daerty94kv5k2n7/AABu9Axewe6mL0NdEX2nG5MIa?dl=0
[image: source image]

Fit ellipse based on color
[image: Fit ellipse based on color]

Re-fit ellipse based on color and edges
[image: Re-fit ellipse based on color and edges]

The Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0TQYREm9uA

Here is source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    cv::Mat capturedImage = imread(argv[1]);

    if( capturedImage.empty() )
    {
        cout << "Couldn't open image " << argv[1] << "\nUsage: fitellipse <image_name>\n";
        return 0;
    }

/*============================= Phase 1: Translate Color Space from RGB to HSV =====================================================*/
    cv::Mat imgHSV;
    cv::cvtColor(capturedImage, imgHSV, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV

    cv::Mat imgGray;
    cv::cvtColor(capturedImage, imgGray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    cv::Mat imgThresholded;
    cv::inRange(imgHSV, cv::Scalar(160, 80, 70), cv::Scalar(179, 255, 255), imgThresholded); //Threshold the image

    //morphological opening
    cv::erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(7, 7)) );
    cv::dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(7, 7)) );
    //morphological closing (removes small holes from the foreground)
    cv::dilate( imgThresholded, imgThresholded, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(7, 7)) );
    cv::erode(imgThresholded, imgThresholded, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(7, 7)) );

    namedWindow("imgThresholded", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("imgThresholded", imgThresholded);

/*============================= Phase 2: Fit a coarse ellipse based on red color ======================================================*/
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(imgThresholded, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cv::Point(0,0));

    size_t index = 0;
    size_t largestSize = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        if (contours[i].size() > largestSize)
        {
            largestSize = contours[i].size();
            index = i;
        }
    }

    if (contours[index].size() < 6)
    {
        cout << "Do not have enough points" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat imgContour;
    cv::Mat(contours[index]).convertTo(imgContour, CV_32F);
    cv::RotatedRect coarseEllipse = cv::fitEllipse(imgContour);

    cv::Mat capturedImageClone = capturedImage.clone();

    ellipse(capturedImageClone, coarseEllipse.center, coarseEllipse.size*0.5f, coarseEllipse.angle, 0.0, 360.0, cv::Scalar(0,255,255), 3, CV_AA);

    namedWindow("capturedImageClone", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("capturedImageClone", capturedImageClone);

/*============================= Phase 3: Re-fit a final ellipse based on combination of color and edge ===============================*/

    double cxc = coarseEllipse.center.x;
    double cyc = coarseEllipse.center.y;
    double ca = coarseEllipse.size.height/2;
    double cb = coarseEllipse.size.width/2;

    cv::Mat mask(capturedImage.rows, capturedImage.cols, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));    
    cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(coarseEllipse.center.x, coarseEllipse.center.y), coarseEllipse.size.height/2 + 100, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), -1);    
    cv::Mat imgMask;
    cv::Mat edges;

    cv::bitwise_and(capturedImage, mask, imgMask);

    namedWindow("imgMask", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("imgMask", imgMask);

    cv::GaussianBlur(imgMask, edges, cv::Size(5,5), 0);
    cv::Canny(edges, edges, 50, 100);

    namedWindow("edges", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("edges", edges);

    cv::findContours(edges, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, cv::Point(0,0));

    index = -1;
    double centerDistance = (numeric_limits<double>::max)();
    double abRatio = (numeric_limits<double>::max)();
    cv::RotatedRect finalEllipse;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        if (contours[i].size() < 500 || i == contours.size() - 1 || i == contours.size() - 2)
        continue;

        cv::Mat(contours[i]).convertTo(imgContour, CV_32F);
        cv::RotatedRect tmpEllipse = cv::fitEllipse(imgContour);

        double txc = tmpEllipse.center.x;
        double tyc = tmpEllipse.center.y;
        double ta = tmpEllipse.size.height/2;
        double tb = tmpEllipse.size.width/2;

        double tmpDis = (cxc - txc) * (cxc - txc) + (cyc - tyc) * (cyc - tyc);

        if (tmpDis < centerDistance && fabs(tb/ta - 1) < abRatio && ta > ca && tb > cb)
        {
            centerDistance = tmpDis;
            abRatio = fabs(tb/ta - 1);
            index = i;
            finalEllipse = tmpEllipse;
        }

   }

   if (index == -1)
        finalEllipse = coarseEllipse;

   ellipse(capturedImage, finalEllipse.center, finalEllipse.size*0.5f, finalEllipse.angle, 0.0, 360.0, cv::Scalar(0,255,255), 3, CV_AA);

   double xc = finalEllipse.center.x;       // center x
   double yc = finalEllipse.center.y;       // center y
   double theta = finalEllipse.angle;       // rotation angle theta
   double a = finalEllipse.size.height / 2; // semi-major axis: a
   double b = finalEllipse.size.width / 2;  // semi-minor axis: b

   double A = a * a * sin(theta) * sin(theta) + b * b * cos(theta) * cos(theta);
   double B = 2 * (b * b - a * a) * sin(theta) * cos(theta);
   double C = a * a * cos(theta) * cos(theta) + b * b * sin(theta) * sin(theta);
   double D = -2 * A * xc - B * yc;
   double E = -B * xc - 2 * C * yc;
   double F = A * xc * xc + B * xc * yc + C * yc * yc - a * a * b * b;

    A = A/F;
    B = B/F;
    C = C/F;
    D = D/F;
    E = E/F;
    F = F/F;

    double ellipseArray[3][3] = {{A, B/2, D/2},
                             {B/2, C, E/2},
                             {D/2, E/2, F}};

    cv::Mat ellipseMatrix(3,3,CV_64FC1, ellipseArray);
    cout << ellipseMatrix << endl;

    namedWindow("capturedImage", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("capturedImage", capturedImage);

    imwrite(argv[2],capturedImage);
    imwrite(argv[3],edges);
    imwrite(argv[4],capturedImageClone);
    imwrite(argv[5],imgMask);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```